# how to add [] chars between numbers of string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replace, regexp-replace

How can I convert the string

> "post54post5 56post6"

to this string?

> "post[54]post[5] [56]post[6]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('post54post5 56post6', '(\d+)', '[\1]', 'g');
-- post[54]post[5] [56]post[6]
```

### Demo

Comment: tanks for answer ...